# Variable not being passed in function in R

Tags: r

I am using [kmeansFilter function from FlowCore](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flowCore/versions/1.38.2/topics/kmeansFilter-class) to create a filter (class?) for downstream analysis.

I am having trouble passing a variable to the function:

```
#install flowCore via BiocManager::install("flowCore")
library(flowCore)
#Working example: 
## Create the filter
kf <- kmeansFilter("FSC-H"=c("Pop1","Pop2","Pop3"), filterId="myKmFilter")

kf@parameters[[1]]
# unitytransform on parameter 'FSC-H'

#Desire: 
channel <- "FSC-H"
kf <- kmeansFilter(channel=c("Pop1","Pop2","Pop3"), filterId="myKmFilter")

kf@parameters[[1]]
# unitytransform on parameter 'channel'
```

`channel` not being passed. I have tried `sym()` and other, but it seems I am missing something.

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT:
as @jay.sf pointed out int he comment, parameters are defined as list. so you can define the first parameter as a list. But `list()` can pass a variable (example below); `list()` in the function `kmeansFilter` does not show this case.

```
tkf <- "test"
    channel <- list(tkf=c("Pop1","Pop2","Pop3")) #tkf passed as "test" 
kf <- kmeansFilter(channel, filterId="myKmFilter")
```

I think the workaround is clear, but it stood out as something if off, and I got curious a bit.

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation you linked to? It clearly states that multiple parameters  should be defined a list. See section `...`.

Comment: Package `flowCore` is not a CRAN package. Where can we find it?

Comment: @jay.sf I still can't see why a variable cannot be passed. Check my edits. Anyways, now I'm just being curious, I have a solution to use for my script.

Comment: @RuiBarradas That's right, it's bioconductor. I edited the post. `BiocManager::install("flowCore")`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to follow the documentation and pass `channel` as a named list. From `help("kmeansFilter")`, section Arguments, my emphasis:

> kmeansFilter are defined by a single flow parameter and an associated list of k population names. They can be given as **a character vector via a named argument**, or as **a list with a single named argument**. In both cases **the name will be used as the flow parameter** and the content of the list or of the argument will be used as population names, after coercing to character.

In the code below I use a list as the flow parameter.

```
channel <- list(`FSC-H` = c("Pop1","Pop2","Pop3"))
kf2 <- kmeansFilter(
  channel, 
  filterId = "myKmFilter"
)

kf2@parameters[[1]]
#unitytransform on parameter 'FSC-H'

kf2
#k-means filter 'myKmFilter' in dimension FSC-H
#with 3 populations (Pop1,Pop2,Pop3)
```

Note that the flow parameter can also be defined with the name between single or double quotes. I have defined it between back ticks but this is not mandatory. The following also works.

```
channel <- list("FSC-H" = c("Pop1","Pop2","Pop3"))
```

If the name is chosen programmatically, then the workaround in the question or to set the name with `names<-` or with `setNames` are the best options.